# How to define logical expressions for platonic solids?

Tags: functions, graphics3d

A more general question would be: How to find logical expressions for 3D-objects described by closed polygon sets?

Finally a simple question is more prolific, therefore:

### How to define logical expressions for platonic solids ?

I study this question for two days now, and I thought, I found an answer already:

```
PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "RegionFunction"]

(* out *)
 Sqrt[2] + 4 Sqrt[3] #3 >= 0 && 
  4 Sqrt[3] #3 <= 3 Sqrt[2] + 8 Sqrt[6] #1 && 
  4 Sqrt[3] (Sqrt[2] #1 + #3) <= 3 Sqrt[2] (1 + 4 #2) && 
  4 (Sqrt[6] #1 + 3 Sqrt[2] #2 + Sqrt[3] #3) <= 3 Sqrt[2] &
```

So far, so good. But then I discovered ...

```
PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "RegionFunction"]

Missing["NotAvailable"]
```

ok, this is not dramatic, I can define this myself. But doing so, I found out, it is better to give up those incomplete and specific `RegionFunction` definitions of Mathematica. This led me back to my question: How to define region functions for the 5 platonic solids  in a better way? What are your ideas, your suggestions?
At the moment I just want to concentrate on the platonics.

```
c = constant = Abs@1; (* -1 <= c <=  +1 *) 
plotPoints = 100/2; (* half value while testing *)

RegionPlot3D[
 And[x + y + z <= c, -x - y + z <= c, 
  x - y - z <= c, -x + y - z <= c, -x - y - z <= c, x + y - z <= c, 
  x - y + z <= c, -x + y + z <= c], {x, -c, c}, {y, -c, c}, {z, -c, 
  c}, PlotPoints -> plotPoints]
```

[image: octahedronRegionFunction]

The octahedron region function could be simplified to:
(not sure, if it's really a good idea )

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Abs@x + Abs@y + Abs@z <= c, {x, -c, +c}, {y, -c, +c}, {z, -c, +c}, 
 PlotPoints -> plotPoints]
```

two region functions for tetrahedrons of interest

```
RegionPlot3D[
 And[x + y - z <= c, +x - y + z <= c, -x + y + z <= c, -x - y - z <= 
   c], {x, -c, +c}, {y, -c, +c}, {z, -c, +c}, PlotPoints -> plotPoints]

RegionPlot3D[
 And[x - y - z <= c, -x - y + z <= c, -x + y - z <= c, +x + y + z <= 
   c], {x, -c, +c}, {y, -c, +c}, {z, -c, +c}, PlotPoints -> plotPoints]
```

## What would be `nice` regionFunctions for `Dodecahedron` or `Icosahedron`, to complete the 5 platonics ?

You may checkout yourself the definitions for `RegionFunction` done by Mathematica. Especially non-convex polyhedrons have no region functions defined. (code from Mathematica, modfied):

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{PolyhedronData[g], PolyhedronData[g, p]}], {{g, "Octahedron",
    "polyhedron" // Style[#, GrayLevel@.4, "Menu"] &}, 
  PolyhedronData[All]}, {{p, "RegionFunction" (* init *), 
   "property" // Style[#, GrayLevel@.4, "Menu"] &}, 
  Complement @@ PolyhedronData /@ {"Properties", "Classes"}}]
```

Comment: These exist in V10 for 151 of the 195 polyhedra in `PolyhedronData[]`, including the Platonic solids.

Comment: `nice` region functions in V10? Can you kindly post me the output of `PolyhedronData["Octahedron","RegionFunction"]` in an answer?

Comment: You can make it shorter with `ContourPlot3D[Norm[{x,y,z},1]==1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1}]`.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose they are nice....They check that a point is inside each facet plane.

```
# -> PolyhedronData[#, "RegionFunction"] & /@ {"Octahedron", 
  "Dodecahedron", "Icosahedron"}
(*
{"Octahedron" -> (2 (#1 + #3) <= Sqrt[2] + 2 #2 && 
     2 (#1 + #2 + #3) <= Sqrt[2] && 2 (#2 + #3) <= Sqrt[2] + 2 #1 && 
     2 #3 <= Sqrt[2] + 2 #1 + 2 #2 && 
     Sqrt[2] + 2 #1 + 2 #2 + 2 #3 >= 0 && 
     2 #1 <= Sqrt[2] + 2 #2 + 2 #3 && 2 #2 <= Sqrt[2] + 2 #1 + 2 #3 &&
      2 (#1 + #2) <= Sqrt[2] + 2 #3 &), 
 "Dodecahedron" -> (5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) + 
       Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] (2 #1 + #3) >= 0 && 
     Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] (2 #1 + #3) <= 5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) && 
     Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] #1 + Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 <= 
      5 (2 + Sqrt[5] + (1 + Sqrt[5]) #2) && 
     Sqrt[2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 <= 2 + Sqrt[5] && 
     Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] #1 + 5 (1 + Sqrt[5]) #2 + 
       Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 <= 5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) && 
     2 Sqrt[5 (5 + 2 Sqrt[5])] #1 + 10 #2 <= 
      5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) + Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 && 
     2 Sqrt[5 (5 + 2 Sqrt[5])] #1 <= 
      5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) + 10 #2 + Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 && 
     5 (1 + Sqrt[5]) #2 <= 
      5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) + Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] #1 + 
       Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 && 
     Sqrt[5/8 + 11/(8 Sqrt[5])] + #3 >= 0 && 
     5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) + Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] #1 + 5 (1 + Sqrt[5]) #2 +
        Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 >= 0 && 
     Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 <= 
      2 Sqrt[5 (5 + 2 Sqrt[5])] #1 + 5 (2 + Sqrt[5] + 2 #2) && 
     10 #2 + Sqrt[10 (5 + Sqrt[5])] #3 <= 
      5 (2 + Sqrt[5]) + 2 Sqrt[5 (5 + 2 Sqrt[5])] #1 &), 
 "Icosahedron" -> (30 #1 + 2 Sqrt[250 - 110 Sqrt[5]] #2 + 10 #3 <= 
      Sqrt[5] (Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + 14 #1 + 2 #3) && 
     2 Sqrt[2] ((-3 + Sqrt[5]) #1 + #3) <= Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]] && 
     10 (3 #1 + #3) <= 
      Sqrt[5] (Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + 14 #1 + 
         2 Sqrt[50 - 22 Sqrt[5]] #2 + 2 #3) && 
     2 (Sqrt[10 - 4 Sqrt[5]] #1 + Sqrt[2] (-5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) #2 + 
         Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[5]] #3) <= Sqrt[10] && 
     2 (Sqrt[10 - 4 Sqrt[5]] #1 + Sqrt[2] (5 - 2 Sqrt[5]) #2 + 
         Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[5]] #3) <= Sqrt[10] && 
     2 Sqrt[5] (7 #1 + #3) <= 
      Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] + 30 #1 + 2 Sqrt[250 - 110 Sqrt[5]] #2 + 
       10 #3 && 
     Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]] + 2 Sqrt[2] (-3 + Sqrt[5]) #1 + 2 Sqrt[2] #3 >=
       0 && 2 Sqrt[5] (7 #1 + Sqrt[50 - 22 Sqrt[5]] #2 + #3) <= 
      Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] + 30 #1 + 
       10 #3 && (-3 + Sqrt[5]) Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]] #1 + 
       2 Sqrt[2] (5 - 2 Sqrt[5]) #2 <= 
      Sqrt[10] + 
       2 Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[5]] #3 && (-3 + Sqrt[5]) Sqrt[
        5 + Sqrt[5]] #1 + 2 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) #2 <= 
      Sqrt[10] + 2 Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[5]] #3 && 
     2 Sqrt[5] (4 #1 + 2 Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[5]] #2 + 7 #3) <= 
      Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] + 20 #1 + 30 #3 && 
     2 Sqrt[2] ((-5 + Sqrt[5]) #1 + (5 - 2 Sqrt[5]) #3) <= Sqrt[
      5 (5 + Sqrt[5])] && 
     2 Sqrt[5] (4 #1 + 7 #3) <= 
      Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] + 20 #1 + 4 Sqrt[5 (5 - 2 Sqrt[5])] #2 + 
       30 #3 && 
     2 (-15 + 7 Sqrt[5]) #3 <= 
      Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] + 2 (-5 + Sqrt[5]) #1 + 
       2 Sqrt[250 - 110 Sqrt[5]] #2 && 
     2 Sqrt[250 - 110 Sqrt[5]] #2 + 2 (-15 + 7 Sqrt[5]) #3 <= 
      Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] + 2 (-5 + Sqrt[5]) #1 && 
     20 #1 + 30 #3 <= 
      Sqrt[5] (Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + 8 #1 + 
         4 Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[5]] #2 + 14 #3) && 
     2 Sqrt[2] (-5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) #3 <= 
      Sqrt[5 (5 + Sqrt[5])] + 2 Sqrt[2] (-5 + Sqrt[5]) #1 && 
     20 #1 + 4 Sqrt[5 (5 - 2 Sqrt[5])] #2 + 30 #3 <= 
      Sqrt[5] (Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + 8 #1 + 14 #3) && 
     2 (-5 + Sqrt[5]) #1 + 2 Sqrt[250 - 110 Sqrt[5]] #2 + 
       2 (15 - 7 Sqrt[5]) #3 <= Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] && 
     2 (-5 + Sqrt[5]) #1 + 2 (15 - 7 Sqrt[5]) #3 <= 
      Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]] + 2 Sqrt[250 - 110 Sqrt[5]] #2 &)}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks (+), for delivery. At the same time it illustrates the problem.

Comment: Yes, too long, it could be done more dense. Honestly, would you like to work with those 2 pages of logical expressions. Of course, content is ok, but the presentation is not!

Comment: @hieron I would let *Mathematica* work with them.  I doubt it would complain. :)  If this is about pencil & paper work, how is it a Q about *Mathematica*?  If not, it seems like a mathematics question.

Comment: Increasing quality and shortening length of an standard output in MMA is quite a good reason for a question?

Comment: In my mind the quality of the built-in functions is rather high.  $n$ linear inequalities, one for each face.  Just my opinion, though.  Well, let's see if someone can improve. :)

Comment: Anyway I'm not happy with this representation. In my opinion it's a contradiction in some way, on one hand, we have some of the most regular objects in universe, on the other hand we have such a bunch of irregular data output

Comment: @hieron So maybe they are *not* so regular in the universe :)

Comment: Look into microscope, Silvia, this little-big universe

Comment: @hieron OK the microscope thing reminds me, maybe there are simple 3D cellular automata rules generating these polyhedrons. But I think the formulae provided by `PolyhedronData[..., "RegionFunction"]` are not optimized for insightful concept but for numerical computing. If you are looking for the former one, you might want to emphasize it in you question.

Comment: @Silvia You're right: insightful concepts would be great. I'm convinced there is a better way to handle logical expressions, still looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different sort of answer, but very V10-style.  The only logical expression however is `Element`, so I'm afraid this will fall short.

```
Clear[regFn, regFn`mesh]; 
regFn`mesh[polyh_] := 
 regFn`mesh[polyh] = 
  ConvexHullMesh@PolyhedronData[polyh, "VertexCoordinates"]

regFn[polyh_] := 
 With[{region = regFn`mesh[polyh]}, {##} ∈ region &]
```

This looks so cute, though:

```
regFn["Icosahedron"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
regFn["Icosahedron"][1/2, 1/2, 1/2]
regFn["Icosahedron"][1/3, 1/3, 1/3]
(*
  False
  True
*)
```

This function is almost as fast as the compiled `PolyhedronData` region function:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

rf1 = regFn["Icosahedron"];
rf2 = PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "RegionFunction"];
rf2C = Compile @@ {{x, y, z}, 
    PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z]};

rf1[1/2, 1/2, 1/2] // AccurateTiming
rf2[1/2, 1/2, 1/2] // AccurateTiming
rf2C[1/2, 1/2, 1/2] // AccurateTiming
(*
  9.6709*10^-6
  0.000285342
  5.22754*10^-6
 *)
```

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the new features in v10. But I guess what OP wants are some mathematical insight, beautiful in concept representations. I'm thinking about something starting from the [crystallographic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_point_group) [point groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions), but I've forgotten my group theory knowledge.. :(

Comment: @Silvia Coxeter's book *Regular Polytopes* might have nice formulas.  I don't have it handy, though.  The problem, IMO, is that the symmetry of dodeca/icosahedra do not match the symmetry of the xyz coordinate system.

Comment: Well you can't have a coordsys matching for all of them :) (or can we?)

Comment: Thanks Michael E2 Despite I can't examine it, it looks good. Time to upgrade to MMA10.